# Quark-Gluon Plasma vs QCD binding energy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, quantum-chromodynamics

The binding energy of nucleons is on the order of around 900 MEV. Yet, Quark-Gluon plasma is observed at around 175-300MEV. This doesn't seem to make any sense - how can only 300 MEV worth of energy break bonds of around 900 MEV? Where does the remaining 600 MEV go?

Answer (score 1):

That ~900 MeV is not binding energy in the same way as say the 13.6eV in the hydrogen atom. The hydrogen atom ground state has a rest mass that is 13.6eV less than the masses of its constituents and you need to add energy to separate them. On the other hand the nucleon mass is much greater than the naive quark masses you can look up in say a particle data book. Naively it would take *no energy* to separate the nucleon into constituents, but confinement doesn't work the same way as a hydrogen atom.

Comment: So melting protons/neutrons/hadrons is an exothermic process (if done at 100% efficiency which isn't feasible but that's beside the point), and you can view the initial heating to trillions of kelvins as an "excitation energy". But I don't understand your "naively it would take no energy" claim - how is that possible with the strong nuclear force? Are you saying that without the strong force, you could separate nucleons into quarks without adding energy - but with the strong force, you need a few hundred MEV "excitation"?

Comment: I'm just saying the sign is flipped from the way you were thinking about things and that explains why you don't need to add ~900MeV in principle. It is not so simple as though there is a potential barrier and if you add the excitation energy you can hop over it and release that ~900MeV. If that were the case the proton would be unstable due to tunneling.